# Does a pendrive store any access logs?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, logging, usb-storage

I have a pendrive, and would like to know how many times was it plugged in/accessed in the past few days. Does the device or the file system store any logs about this?

I am using Windows 10, the flash drive's file system is FAT32.

Comment: Which operating system are you working on and which filesystem does the pendrive have?

Comment: The pendrive itself most likely does not have this. But if you use windows, the event-log most likely does have this.

Comment: @mtak I am using windows 10, the flash drive's partition is FAT32

Comment: @LPChip The drive may have been used in other computers, not a certain one.

Comment: Seems its not going to be possible then.

Comment: EXT saves the last mount date/time, and mountpoint too. Unless it's mounted read-only. FYI the device's own firmware could store who knows what, they've got their own programming & microprocessors for keeping track of the good & bad sectors & swapping them, could really be doing anything

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is no insert/eject information stored in the drive.**

> In Linux, the insert/removal events can be found in syslog.
>
> So it is possible to see if USB drives have been used on a particular system

But there is no such log on the device itself.